# How can I start and stop multiple JavaScript timers?

Tags: javascript, timer

I want to run a timer in JavaScript for 30 seconds, play a beeping .WAV file, then count 10 seconds and play the beep again. I want this to repeat until either a desired time is hit or the user intervenes and clicks a stop button.

This is how I've implemented it:

```
function startWorkOut(param) {

        if (param === 1) {
            setTimeout(playBeep, 30000); //30 second workout
        }
        else if (param === 0) {
            setTimeout(playBeep, 10000); //10 second rest
        }
        return;
}

function playBeep() {

        beep.play(); //already loaded above this snippet

        i++; //simple switch for going back and forth between 30 & 10 secs
        if (i % 2 === 1) {
            startWorkOut(0);
        }
        else startWorkOut(1);

        return;     

}
```

The problem is I don't know how to stop it. Because these two functions are calling each other back and forth, I need to know how to put in some sort of a manual break.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assign it to a variable

```
 var beepTimer = setTimeout(playBeep, 30000); //30 second workout

clearTimeout(beepTimer);  // This will clear that timer
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but wouldn't it be pointless to run clearTimeout? I thought that the whole point of setTimeout was that it ran once, as opposed to setInterval. beepTimer would only be in scope inside of that function, right?

Comment: right.. I was just giving an example. But you need to declare the variable outside the  function scope , So that it can be scope in other functions as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
   var timerConst;
    function startWorkOut(param) {

            if (param === 1) {
                timerConst  = setTimeout(playBeep, 30000); //30 second workout
            }
            else if (param === 0) {
                timerConst  = setTimeout(playBeep, 10000); //10 second rest
            }
            return;
    }

    function playBeep() {

            beep.play(); //already loaded above this snippet

            i++; //simple switch for going back and forth between 30 & 10 secs
            if (i % 2 === 1) {
                startWorkOut(0);
            }
            else startWorkOut(1);

            return;     

    }

   function stop(){
          clearTimeout(timerConst);
   }
```

Comment: Doesn't timerConst go out of scope since it's in a different function?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed that you declared it globally.

Answer (score 0):

Store the reference returned by **setTimeout** or **setInterval** method and then use window.clearTimeout or window.clearInterval to remove those timers. Example:

```
var ref1 = window.setTimeout(function() {your code}, 5000);
var ref2 = window.setInterval(function() {your code}, 5000);
```

An then remove them using the following code:

```
window.clearTimeout(ref1);
window.clearInterval(ref2);
```

Hope it help.

Comment: there's no need to use the window object

Comment: clearTimeout and clearInterval are routines of window object. You may not specify window before these functions. However to be clear I think we must write their prefix.

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/db8hX/)***

"I want to run a timer in JavaScript for 30 seconds, play a beeping .WAV file, then count 10 seconds and play the beep again. I want this to repeat until either a desired time is hit or the user intervenes and clicks a stop button."

Timers are 3 and 1 second for brevity

```
var playing;//variable for timer
function startWorkOut(){
 var entry = playing === void 0;//true if playing is undefined
 var interval = entry? 3000 : 1000;//first entry is 3s timer, others are 1s
 if(!entry)playBeep();//play a beep except when the workout timer is first started
 playing = setTimeout(startWorkOut,interval);//play a beep in either 3s or 1s
}

function stopWorkOut(){
 clearTimeout(playing);//stops timer
 playing = undefined;//restores variable state
}
```